# How to use JSON/YAML file with Gridsome

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gridsome

I want to build a gridsome application which works with json or YAML file.

I want to get values of files located at "./data/" folder from Vue components and keep the graphQL data layer.
In other terms, expose in graphQL data from files.

*profile.json*

```
{
    "name": "Lorem"
}
```

*config.json*

```
{
    "layout": "default",
    "theme": "blue"
}
```

I want to access the name value in a way like this:

```
$page.data.profile.name
$page.data.config.theme
```

Or

```
$data.profile.name
$data.config.theme
```

have I to deal with @gridsome/source-filesystem and @gridsome/transformer-json plugins ?
Or maybe manually adding the 'Data' collection in server and add new node for each file ?

I have tested both and exploring graphQL API return an error : "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have local files, you can add them this way:

```
import temperatures from '~/data/four.json'
import east from '~/data/east.json'
import southwest from '~/data/southwest.json'
import whd from '~/data/whd.json'
import thirteen from '~/data/thirteen.json'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      temperatures,
      east,
      thirteen,
      whd,
      southwest,
    }
  },
```

Basically i created a data folder within my pages directory and then placed the files in their. You then link to them in the script tag and call for them with a return function.

In your template tag you would do something like this:

```
<template>
<div>
 {{ temperatures }}
</div>
</template>
```